# Is kuon a word? What word am I thinking of?

Tags: single-word-requests

I thought kuon was a word that meant any type of small riddle or puzzle.

Eg: I thought that 'When a tree falls in the forest does anyone hear it?' was a kuon.

But my googling finds no evidence for it.

I am not thinking of the word enigma or haiku either.

Is this all in my head or did I invent a new word ...?

Comment: https://www.dictionary.com/browse/koan - doesn't mean quite what you think it means, but I'm sure it's the word you were thinking of.

Comment: I have to concur with nnnnnn: koan is likely the word you seek.

Answer (score 6):

a ***koan*** is defined ([M/W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/koan)) as

> a paradox to be meditated upon that is used to train Zen Buddhist
> monks to abandon ultimate dependence on reason and to force them into
> gaining sudden intuitive enlightenment

Comment: my google-fu is bad to not solve that myself. Suprised results didn't point me in the right direction though. Thank you!